# Dudas con la integración de pasarela de pago

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pago-in-app

estoy recien graduado y dado que me pillo el confinamiento por la pandemia no he podido tener unas practicas decentes por lo que decidí hacer una app personal para venta de productos, lo que pasa es que no soy capaz de entender como integrar una pasarela de pago a mi app. Quiero integrar Google Pay ya que me parece la pasarela más optima y segura. Lo que pasa es que no entiendo la documentación y no encuentro videos que lo expliquen bien y los post que veo son en kotlin y yo soy programador de java. Si alguien me puede ayudar le estaré eternamente agradecido, si es necesario para una comunicaccion directa estoy dispuesto a dar mi correo o tlfno para whatsapp o telegram.
Un saludo

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que leas como preguntar -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Para poder ayudarte debes proveernos un ejemplo de código de algo que hayas hecho y se pueda reproducir. Debes agregar cuál es tu problema específico. De otra forma no será posible ayudarte

Comment: Dado que ahora android es kotlin-first, se recomienda encarecidamente migrar a kotlin. Si sabes programar en java, te tomará maximo una semana aprenderlo. El android team ya tiene varios post y videos sobre sus ventajas. Según su [blog oficial](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/fewer-crashes-and-more-stability-with-kotlin-b606c6a6ac04), hay empresas que redujeron sus crashes un 50% desde que migraron a kotlin.